# How to sort a list according to another list? Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.3

So if I have one list:

```
name = ['Megan', 'Harriet', 'Henry', 'Beth', 'George']
```

And I have another list where each value represents the names in the right order

```
score_list = [9, 6, 5, 6, 10]
```

So Megan = 9 and Beth = 6 (this is from a dictionary by the way)

How would I sort name alphabetically but keep the score_list matching name?
I have done the with sorting numbers using the bubble sort method but not strings.

Comment: Take a look at the zip function.

Comment: When you find yourself needing this kind of operation, even though this is simple enough to write, think if it's better to have a "list of structs" or a "struct of lists".

Comment: Since those lists are coming from a dict it would be better to build a list of tuples directly from the dict, rather than extracting the lists separately then zipping them back together into a list of tuples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort them at the same time as tuples by using `zip`. The sorting will be by name:

```
tuples = sorted(zip(name, score_list))
```

And then

```
name, score_list = [t[0] for t in tuples], [t[1] for t in tuples]
```

Answer (score 7):

One obvious approach would be to `zip` both the list sort it and then unzip it

```
>>> name, score = zip(*sorted(zip(name, score_list)))
>>> name
('Beth', 'George', 'Harriet', 'Henry', 'Megan')
>>> score
(6, 10, 6, 5, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but when I load the program It says 'TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable' I am running 3.3.5 python btw

Comment: @Goregius and for anyone seeing this in 2022, you do not subscript a zip, you convert it to a list

Answer (score 1):

The correct way if you have a dict is to sort the items by the key:

```
name = ['Megan', 'Harriet', 'Henry', 'Beth', 'George']

score_list = [9, 6, 5, 6, 10]
d = dict(zip(name, score_list))

from operator import itemgetter
print(sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(0)))
[('Beth', 6), ('George', 10), ('Harriet', 6), ('Henry', 5), ('Megan', 9)]
```

Comment: Yes missed that he has a dict

Answer (score 1):

Consider a third-party tool [`more_itertools.sort_together`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.sort_together):

**Given**

```
import more_itertools as mit


name = ["Megan", "Harriet", "Henry", "Beth", "George"]
score_list = [9, 6, 5, 6, 10]
```

**Code**

```
mit.sort_together([name, score_list])
# [('Beth', 'George', 'Harriet', 'Henry', 'Megan'), (6, 10, 6, 5, 9)]
```

Install [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) via `> pip install more_itertools`.